# How do I import AppConfig.java class in Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm following the docs of spring framework and trying to realize it by code, but I'm stuck on AppConfig class.
What dependency do I need to import AppConfig class?
I've injected spring-beans, spring-web, spring-context, spring-webmvc already and my spring version is 5.2.5.RELEASE.

I googled "AppConfig cannot be resolved to a type" but couldn't get anything about it.

And this is the part of code from https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#spring-web

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

        // Load Spring web application configuration
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class); // <-- this is the part I need AppConfig.

        // Create and register the DispatcherServlet
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("app", servlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/app/*");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe AppConfig is a configuration bean that you need to create that contains all your bean definitions - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `Configuration` bean first named **AppConfig** .

Some thing like below:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
 
    @Bean(name="demoService")
    public DemoClass service() 
    {
        
    }
}
```

You can find plenty of exmaples on web. One Example - [Here](https://zetcode.com/spring/configuration/)

Comment: Thanks. you finished my search of 2 days.

Comment: @Flippingflop : No issues. Keep learning and keep exploring.